# Show wix installer conditional UI step

Tags: wix

I would like to do this.

Check if a registry key exist. If it does, use the value as installdir. If it doesn't, show UI step to select a path and then use it as installdir but also create a registry key and set the value to the given path. The next time I run the installer the registry key should be found and not show that UI step.

Thankful for any help I can get!!

Answer (score 1):

This is quite a common scenario and known within WiX as the Remember Property pattern.

A good explanation can be found on [Rob Mensching's blog](http://robmensching.com/blog/posts/2010/5/2/the-wix-toolsets-remember-property-pattern/)

Comment: Thank you. I had a look at the blog and also took a pluralsight tutorial but I can't get match it with my scenario. There are always something missing from what I need.